# Can ChromeDriver for Selenium run for different User?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

my Brother and I are running two different Scripts for Selenium with Python on a virtual Server with different Users. I can't start my script and always get the Error "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)"

Does anybody know, if you can run the WebDriver / ChromeDriver with different Users parallel? Or could this be a reason for our or special my problem?

Thanks!

Edit:

I've found the Problem and Solution!
With the new Version of Chrome they've changed something with the headless mode. The old code was options.add_argument('--headless') and I had to change it to options.add_argument("--headless=new") and now it seems to work pretty finde.